How to stop showing SQL queries of a web application in Browser's Inspect elements?
I have a web application written in express.js and php 8.2.   Currently, anyone can right lick in chrome or edge chromium browser and go to inspect element>>network tab and click on data elements and there all sql queries from that page is exposed for anyone to copy along with values in the where clause of these sql queries.
This is happening both with Express.js and PHP connectivity to MYSQL.
How can I prevent such queries to stop showing up or in inspect element?
Thanks,
Darsh

Don't expose SQL in your web API. Implement an API on the server that abstracts the SQL. Its that simple. Anything that you do on the client (including requests made by the client) is inherently visible to the user.

What does your PHP backend do at the moment?

The PHP does database operations on various tables - Insert, Update, Delete, Query.
In technical sense, how do I not expose SQL in these APIs?  Is there an article link you can share please?

Read any book on HTTP API design. Your PHP shouldn't be taking requests for the SQL, but your application level operations.

What about on the wire?

Related: Cient side coding: How to prevent malicious use?

How do you prevent SQL from showing up in the browser's network debugging panel?
Don't send SQL from the front end.
This is a lesson learned the hard way. You cannot trust anything from the client. More generally this is known as a SQL injection attack and it is a pretty serious vulnerability. It is consistently in the OWASP Top Ten vulnerability list, and is a perennial favorite amongst attackers.
From what I understand, JavaScript in the user's browser is sending strings of SQL to an Express.js or PHP application residing on a web server. There are a couple general ways to fix this, but there are a thousand concrete implementations:

Send HTTP requests and pass key-value pairs of parameters in the query string or the HTTP body if sending a POST request. This can be done with a plain old <form> tag with <input>s. Mozilla Developer Network has an introduction to this worth reading.
Submit the form and send data using JavaScript.

Serialize a JavaScript object as JSON and send it as the body of a POST to the server. JavaScript can do this with the fetch API which gives your web page a more responsive feel.
Send XML via an XMLHttpRequest (i.e. old school AJAX), although you can send any data type, including JSON.



Each of these techniques is a big topic on it's own, and using any of them will require replumbing your express.js or PHP backends. Server side code will need to be written to process the request and perform more of the business logic, which is then translated to SQL queries in express.js or PHP.
Guarding against SQL injection attacks doesn't end there. If you concatenate user input with a string to form a SQL statement then you've just moved your original problem to the backend. A search field in the user interface just becomes another avenue for an attacker to send malicious SQL to your database. When using PHP, use prepared statements. A cursory search for how to use prepared statements in Node.js did not give me a satisfactory example, but "SQL prepared statement" is a good thing to search for. Prepared statements give you a safe way to include user input in a SQL query, insert, update, or delete.
Going a little bit further, you need to ensure requests are authenticated if users are allowed to modify data. There are a variety of ways to do this. Some buzzwords to search are

Cookie authentication in PHP or Express.js
Federated authentication
OpenID Connect
OAuth 2.0
SAML (Security Assertion Markup Language)
JSON Web Tokens (i.e. JWT tokens, and yes the "T" in JWT means "token" but people say it twice anyways)

Additionally, you need to segregate the web server from the database server. Install and properly configure firewalls to block all network traffic except to and from nodes that should talk to one another. For example, block ALL traffic to your database on every port except traffic originating from your web server. And even then, only allow traffic on the one port the database listens to.
Next, disallow all incoming traffic to your web server except port 443. You should be running an HTTPS connection so traffic to and from browsers is encrypted. If your web server doesn't need to call out to external services, block all outgoing traffic from the web server. Firewall rules limiting network traffic is your first defense against attackers, and helps limit the blast radius of any successful incursions. Beyond the OWASP Top Ten, read about zero trust security.
Fixing the issue is several orders of magnitude more effort and higher in complexity than you realize, but it is absolutely necessary. If the system you describe is operational in the public Internet, take it down immediately! If this resides on an internal network, then it is less exposed, but this assumes the internal network is properly secured. Even if this system is internal, fix this ASAP!
Lastly, if this was done as an academic pursuit or for experimental purposes, and it is not exposed to the Internet, then you can relax a little bit.
I highly advise you to read up on web applications and cyber security. These are very big topics. Web application development is a very enjoyable occupation, but it comes with some real challenges. The security risk profile of the World Wide Web is a dumpster fire and always has been. With the proper security considerations and coding practices, you can at least keep the fire in the dumpster without burning down the whole neighborhood.

Hello Greg,
Following your guidelines,  this is how we are writing to database now.  Will this prevent SQL injection attacks?
function getUserData(){$.ajax({url:SITEURL+"aj/setup/",method:"POST",data:{REQUEST:"get_user_entry_data",is_html:!0},beforeSend:function(){$("#results").fadeOut(500),$(".rploader").fadeIn(800)},success:function(e){setTimeout(function(){$(".rploader").hide(),$("#results").html(e),$("#results").fadeIn(500),$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(),dataTableDefaultOrderOff("table1"),$("#table1_filter").hide()},1e3)}})}

@virtualtransfer, I amended my answer to include a link to more information, which is also here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript
